# Force derived class to call base class function. How do I force the base class function to use virtual base class version of functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, derived-class

Suppose I have the following code

```
class A{
public:
   void f1()
   {
       /* 
        * Other functions that happen here.
        * These calls needs to be made at A's f1() function
        * And cannot be in derived class.
        */    
       f2();
   }
  
   virtual void f2()
   {
       std::cout << "I am base class" << std::endl;
   }
};

class B : A 
{
public: 
    void f2()   
    {
         std::cout << "I am derived class" << std::endl;
    } 
  
    void f3()
    {
        A::f1();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.f3();
    return 0;
}
```

The output above is

```
I am derived class
```

The limitation I have here is that I can't change class A in any way.
Another limitation is that f2() needs to be called through f1(). A::f3() cannot call f1(). The call to f1() needs to be made to A since A's f1() does other things and B cannot override it.

Is there a way to force A::f2() be called when B::f3() is called? In other words, when we ask for the base version, how do we enforce all other functions called within the base class, to use the base version. In this example, that would be f2().

The question marked as duplicate is simply asking to call a parent function from a derived function with no other functions in the called function that overwritten.

Please note that a static cast of A to call f1 will result in the derived class's f2 function to be called.

Comment: _Is there a way to force A::f2() be called when B::f3() is called?_ Yes. Replace `A::f1();` by `A::f2();` in `B::f3();`. [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fa00b90b94d83e1)

Comment: But I need it be called from A. Let me modify the question.

Comment: Change `f1` to call `A::f2`; if you can't change `A`, then no, you can't.

Comment: I updated the question. The original version didn't show what I needed. I have two limitations. I basically need the base class to call its base versions when there derived class has a derived version.

Comment: So, if you need A::f1 to call A::f2, replace the line in A::f1 `f2()` to be `A::f2()`

Comment: The point is that A is also doing other things, then it needs to fall f2().

Comment: 1) Don't override f2 in B. or 2) Make a temporary A that is a sliced copy of the current object and do the operation using that. (Wouldn't preserve any mutations.)

Comment: What you are asking to do is basically impossible in the way you are describing. Maybe explain what problem you are actually having, so people can suggest ways to fix it. This sounds to me like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I think Im pretty clear on the problem I am having. I have limitations and perhaps the answer is that its impossible..